# REGEDIT. Creating an additional option "Open in %program%" for a specific extension

Tags: windows-10, regedit

It is necessary to add the option "open in %my program%" to the context menu for avi files without changing the default program.

Keys were added according to various manuals:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.avi\shell]
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.avi\shell\my_application]
@="my app title"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\shtuller\\AppData\\Roaming\\my_app\\icon_64.ico"
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.avi\shell\my_application\command]
@="\"C:\\User\\\\shtuller\\AppData\\Roaming\\my_app\\open.bat\" \"%1\""
```

and

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\my_application]
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\my_application\shell]
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\my_application\shell\Open]
"FriendlyAppName"="my app title"
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\my_application\shell\Open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\shtuller\\AppData\\Roaming\\my_app\\open.bat\" \"%1\""
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\my_application\SupportedTypes]
".avi"=""
```

However, all this did not give the desired effect. What could be the problem?

Comment: What version of Windows? 11?

Comment: @Gantendo, win 10 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.avi\Shell\my_application]
@="my app title"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\shtuller\\AppData\\Roaming\\my_app\\icon_64.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.avi\Shell\my_application\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\shtuller\\AppData\\Roaming\\my_app\\open.bat\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: And why didn't I try to duplicate the entry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT myself? Thanks)